# problema con datatable y etiqueta <a>

Tags: javascript, datatable

Tengo el siguiente problema con mi datatable que que carga bien los datos, me muestra los link tipo btn que deseo agregar segun el valor de una celda (estado), pero una funcion que quiero llamar al hacer click no me funciona, no sé mu bien como explicarlo,el onclick="carga_modal('+ row.fk +');" no me funciona, el resto si,  les paso mi código, intenten con comillas simples, que es lo normal, luego dobles, etc, si miro el html, mi elemento se ve así:

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-flat" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHistorico" onclick="carga_modal(+ row.fk +)" ;=""><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Es ahí me da el error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Cuando mi elemento se ve asi:

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-flat" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHistorico" onclick="carga_modal(M0FITXg5WWVqZ1NNaFlqdjF2Vlg5QT09)" ;=""><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
```

me da siguiente error al hacer click:
(índice):455 Uncaught ReferenceError: M0FITXg5WWVqZ1NNaFlqdjF2Vlg5QT09 is not defined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((índice):455:57)

Gracias

```
 
<script type ="text/javascript">


  var  json=<?php echo $ins_trabajo->listar_trabajo();?>;
   $('#trabajos_list').dataTable({
  
      responsive: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      destroy: true,
      deferRender: true,
      data: json.aaData,
      scrollX: true,

    "language": {
           "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        columns: [
            {"data": "fk"},
            {"data": "tcodigo"},
            {"data": "fecha_r"},
            {"data": "cliente"},
            {"data": "paciente"},
            {"data": "producto"},
            {"data": "cantidad"},
            {"data": "precio"},
            {"data": "total"},
            {"data": "estado"},
            {"data": "obs"}
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [0],
                visible: false,
            },         
            {
                orderable: false,
                targets: [-1],
                class: 'text-center',
                orderable: false,               
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                  switch(row.estado) {
                    case "Recepcionado":
                      var buttons = '<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-flat" href="<?php echo SERVERURL.DASHBOARD?>/trabajos-entrega/'+ row.fk + '/" ><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>'
                      var buttonsMov = ''
                      var buttonsFin = ''
                      break;

                    case "En Tránsito":
                      var buttons =    '<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-flat" href="<?php echo SERVERURL.DASHBOARD?>/trabajos-entrega/'+ row.fk + '/" ><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>'
                      var buttonsMov = '<a class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-flat" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHistorico" onclick="carga_modal(+ row.fk +)";><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>'
                      var buttonsFin = ''     
                      break;

                      case "En Prueba":
                        var buttons =    '<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-flat" href="<?php echo SERVERURL.DASHBOARD?>/trabajos-entrega/'+ row.fk + '/" ><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>'
                        var buttonsMov = '<a class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-flat" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHistorico" onclick="carga_modal('+row.fk+');"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>'
                        var buttonsFin = ''
                       break;

                      case "Finalizado":
                        var buttons = ''
                        var buttonsMov = ''
                        var buttonsFin = '<a class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-flat" href="<?php echo SERVERURL.DASHBOARD?>/trabajos-entrega/'+ row.fk + '/" ><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></a>'
                       break;
                    default:
                      // code block
                  }
                  return  buttons += buttonsMov+ buttonsFin;
               },
            },
          ],       
   })   
   function carga_modal(id){
      alert(id);
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Si es un botón no uses la etiqueta anchor (<a>) usa un button o un input, no he ido muy profundo en tu error pero tal vez eso solucione.

Comment: @NicolásArévalo es un anchor class btn

Comment: estas contatenando row.fk directo y te lo toma como si quisieras pasar una variabe llamada M0FITXg5WWVqZ1NNaFlqdjF2Vlg5QT09 que no existe, tienes que concatenarlo como texto previamente, podria ser en otra variablle var row_fk = "'" + row.fk+"'";  y despues usar esa en carga_modal

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de otra manera, pues el row.fk, ya lo tengo cuando cargo al data table, entonces al anchor llamo a la funcion cargar_modal sin parapemotrs y funciona perfecto. gracias